# POST request with Alamofire and deeply nested dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, rest, api, alamofire

Whenever I send some request with basic parameters, it works like a charm, for example:

```
let parametersServices  = [
    "name": [
        "first": "\(givenName)",
        "last": "\(familyName)"
    ]
]
```

But if I send parameters with deep nesting, it does not make any effect on those deeply nested parameters, for example:

```
let parametersServices  = [
    "name": [
        "first": "\(givenName)",
        "last": "\(familyName)"
    ],
    "services" : [
        "mentoring": [
            "profileId" : "id123",
            "title" : "mentor"     
        ]
    ]
]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is such type of PATCH does not supported to modify deeply nested profileId ?

Because if I try simply create new user with same parameters, it works fine, however there it does not accept changes with PATCH for existing items.

Comment: I think there is server side parsing issue.

Comment: I have been using `Alamofire`, nested params is fine. Yours look okay too. Like what @Mr.UB mention, could be server side parsing issue. Also, you mention `POST` in your question title, but `PATCH` in your description. Maybe is one of the type that is causing error.

Comment: Well, if I do a POST request trying to modify something it returns 404 from server, which should be normal. But when I do a PATCH it return 200, but nested values are not changed.